# How to change the values of spinner and radio button if I click on a row from jtable (must depend on the values form jtable)

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable, spinner

If I click a row(JTABLE), it must display the specific values back to the textfields/combobox/radiobutton/spinner. But in my case, it's just hard to retrieve the values back to the RADIO BUTTON and SPINNER.

```
package coffeeshop;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class coffeeframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public coffeeframe() {
        initComponents();
        ArrayList coffeeArray = new ArrayList();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        table = new javax.swing.JTable();
        btnAdd = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        name = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        coffeeType = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        coffeeName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        coffeePrice = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        quanOrder = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        dinein = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        togo = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 51));

        table.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        table.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 0, 51));
        table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Customer", "Coffee Type", "Coffee Name", "Price", "Order Mode", "Quantity", "Total"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false, false, false, false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        table.setGridColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 102));
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                tableMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(table);

        btnAdd.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 204));
        btnAdd.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        btnAdd.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        btnAdd.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/coffeeshop/Add-icon (1).png"))); // NOI18N
        btnAdd.setText("ADD ORDER");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAddActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel1.setBackground(java.awt.Color.gray);
        jPanel1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("Customer");

        name.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 3, 11)); // NOI18N
        name.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        name.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                nameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        coffeeType.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        coffeeType.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        coffeeType.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Choose", "Esprezo                        $20", "Green Tea Frappe      $75", "Barako        $22", "Black Coffee              $28" }));
        coffeeType.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                coffeeTypeItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        coffeeType.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                coffeeTypeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel3.setText("Coffee name");

        coffeeName.setEditable(false);
        coffeeName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 3, 11)); // NOI18N
        coffeeName.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        coffeeName.setText(" ");
        coffeeName.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                coffeeNameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel2.setText("Coffee Type");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel4.setText("Coffee price");

        coffeePrice.setEditable(false);
        coffeePrice.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 3, 11)); // NOI18N
        coffeePrice.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        coffeePrice.setText(" ");

        quanOrder.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 3, 11)); // NOI18N
        quanOrder.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 100, 1));

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel5.setText("Quantity");

        buttonGroup1.add(dinein);
        dinein.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        dinein.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        dinein.setSelected(true);
        dinein.setText("Dine-In");
        dinein.setBorder(null);
        dinein.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                dineinActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        buttonGroup1.add(togo);
        togo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        togo.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        togo.setText("To-Go");
        togo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                togoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(coffeeName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 70, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(name)
                                    .addComponent(coffeeType, 0, 163, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addGap(112, 112, 112))))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(85, 85, 85)
                        .addComponent(dinein, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(togo)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)))
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(coffeePrice, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(quanOrder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(25, 25, 25))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(17, 17, 17)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(coffeeType, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(coffeePrice, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(coffeeName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(togo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(dinein, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addComponent(quanOrder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jButton2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 204, 204));
        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        jButton2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/coffeeshop/edit-icon.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("EDIT ORDER");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(239, 234, 234));
        jButton3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/coffeeshop/trash-icon.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText(" ");

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 201, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 129, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(btnAdd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 129, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 129, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 115, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnAdd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        try{
            int total = Integer.parseInt(coffeePrice.getText()) * (Integer)quanOrder.getValue();
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
            Coffee coffee = new Coffee(name.getText(),coffeeType.getSelectedItem().toString(),coffeeName.getText(),Integer.parseInt(coffeePrice.getText()),buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand(),(Integer)quanOrder.getValue(),total);

            coffeeArray.add(coffee);
            if(name.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Complete the order details!");
            }else if(buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand()== null){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Complete the order details!");
            }else{
                   String customerName = name.getText();
                   String cofType = coffeeType.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   String cofName = coffeeName.getText();
                   int price = Integer.parseInt(coffeePrice.getText());
                   String OrderMode= buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand();
                   int quantity = (Integer)quanOrder.getValue();

                   Object[] rowCoffee = {customerName,cofType,cofName,price,OrderMode,quantity,total};
                   model.addRow(rowCoffee);
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException | HeadlessException e){
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Complete the order details!");

        }

    }                                      

    private void coffeeTypeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
          String str_coffee_name = (String)coffeeType.getSelectedItem();
          String input_coffee_name = str_coffee_name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]","");
          coffeeName.setText(input_coffee_name);

          String str_coffee_price = (String)coffeeType.getSelectedItem();
          String input_coffee_price = str_coffee_price.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
          coffeePrice.setText(input_coffee_price);
    }                                          

    private void coffeeNameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void togoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        togo.setActionCommand("TO-GO");

    }                                    

    private void dineinActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        dinein.setActionCommand("DINE-IN");


    }                                      

    private void nameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void coffeeTypeItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
        int i = table.getSelectedRow();
        int total = Integer.parseInt(coffeePrice.getText()) * (Integer)quanOrder.getValue();

           if(i >= 0) 
                {
                   model.setValueAt(name.getText(), i, 0);
                   model.setValueAt(coffeeType.getSelectedItem(), i, 1);
                   model.setValueAt(coffeeName.getText(), i, 2);
                   model.setValueAt(Integer.parseInt(coffeePrice.getText()), i, 3);
                   model.setValueAt(buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand(), i, 4);
                   model.setValueAt((Integer)quanOrder.getValue(), i, 5);
                   model.setValueAt(total, i, 6);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Update Error");
                }

    }                                        

    private void tableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
      try{
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
          name.setText(model.getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
          coffeeType.setSelectedItem(table.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
          coffeeName.setText(model.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
          coffeePrice.setText(model.getValueAt(row, 3).toString());
          quanOrder.setValue(model.getValueAt(row, 5).toString());
      }catch(Exception e){

      }

    }                                  

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(coffeeframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(coffeeframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(coffeeframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(coffeeframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new coffeeframe().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAdd;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField coffeeName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField coffeePrice;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> coffeeType;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton dinein;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField name;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner quanOrder;
    private javax.swing.JTable table;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton togo;
    // End of variables declaration                   
ArrayList<Coffee> coffeeArray = new ArrayList<>();
int length = 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't post corrections in comment, but rather edit your original question. Try to add more description and explanation about the problem and the code too, anything to help us out and to help us understand both.

Comment: Also, best to create and post a [mcve] so that we can compile and run your code ourselves. This is not your full program and not a link to code, but rather the smallest code possible that compiles, runs, and demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2):

> How to change the values of spinner and radio button

- The spinner should be easily settable by calling its `setValue(...)` method, and passing in the number from the selected table row item.
- For the JRadioButtons, probably the easiest solution is to use a Map that maps the selection to its radio button, and then using this map to get a reference to the proper JRadioButton, and calling `setSelected(true)` on it.

For an example, and for an example of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please have a look at:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CoffeeMcve extends JPanel {
    private CoffeeTableModel tableModel = new CoffeeTableModel();
    private JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
    private Map<OrderMode, ButtonModel> modeButtonMap = new EnumMap<>(OrderMode.class);
    private JSpinner quantSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 0, 20, 1));
    private JTextField nameTField = new JTextField(10);
    private ButtonGroup modeBtnGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    public CoffeeMcve() {
        JPanel modePanel = new JPanel();
        modePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Order Mode"));
        for (OrderMode mode : OrderMode.values()) {
            JRadioButton rBtn = new JRadioButton(mode.getText());
            rBtn.setActionCommand(mode.toString());
            modeBtnGroup.add(rBtn);
            modePanel.add(rBtn);
            modeButtonMap.put(mode, rBtn.getModel());
        }

        JPanel orderPanel = new JPanel();
        orderPanel.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
        orderPanel.add(nameTField);
        orderPanel.add(new JLabel("Quantity:"));
        orderPanel.add(quantSpinner);
        orderPanel.add(modePanel);
        orderPanel.add(new JButton(new AddAction("Add", KeyEvent.VK_A)));

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new OrderModeColumnRenderer());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(orderPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new MyTableListener());
    }

    public void setOrderData(CoffeeOrder2 order) {
        nameTField.setText(order.getName());
        quantSpinner.setValue(order.getQuant());
        ButtonModel btnModel = modeButtonMap.get(order.getOrderMode());
        modeBtnGroup.setSelected(btnModel, true);
    }

    private class MyTableListener implements ListSelectionListener {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                int index = table.getSelectedRow();
                CoffeeOrder2 order = tableModel.getRow(index);
                setOrderData(order);
            }
        }

    }

    private class OrderModeColumnRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if (value != null && value instanceof OrderMode) {
                value = ((OrderMode) value).getText();
            }
            return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        }
    }

    private class AddAction extends AbstractAction {
        public AddAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String name = nameTField.getText();
            int quant = (int) quantSpinner.getValue();
            ButtonModel model = modeBtnGroup.getSelection();
            if (model != null) {
                String actionCommand = model.getActionCommand();
                OrderMode orderMode = OrderMode.valueOf(actionCommand);
                CoffeeOrder2 coffeeOrder2 = new CoffeeOrder2(name, quant, orderMode);
                tableModel.addRow(coffeeOrder2);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        CoffeeMcve mainPanel = new CoffeeMcve();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CoffeeMcve");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CoffeeTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    public static final String[] TITLES = {"Name", "Quantity", "Order Mode"};

    public CoffeeTableModel() {
        super(TITLES, 0);
    }

    public void addRow(CoffeeOrder2 coffee2) {
        Vector<Object> rowData = new Vector<>();
        rowData.add(coffee2.getName());
        rowData.add(coffee2.getQuant());
        rowData.add(coffee2.getOrderMode());
        super.addRow(rowData);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        Object value = getValueAt(0, columnIndex);
        if (value == null) {
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        } else {
            return value.getClass();
        }
    }

    public CoffeeOrder2 getRow(int rowIndex) {
        if (rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex >= getRowCount()) {
            String text = "For rowIndex: " + rowIndex;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(text);
        }

        String name = getValueAt(rowIndex, 0).toString();
        int quant = (int) getValueAt(rowIndex, 1);
        OrderMode orderMode = (OrderMode) getValueAt(rowIndex, 2);

        return new CoffeeOrder2(name, quant, orderMode);
    }
}

class CoffeeOrder2 {
    private String name;
    private int quant;
    private OrderMode orderMode;

    public CoffeeOrder2(String name, int quant, OrderMode orderMode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quant = quant;
        this.orderMode = orderMode;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getQuant() {
        return quant;
    }

    public void setQuant(int quant) {
        this.quant = quant;
    }

    public OrderMode getOrderMode() {
        return orderMode;
    }

    public void setOrderMode(OrderMode orderMode) {
        this.orderMode = orderMode;
    }

}

enum OrderMode {
    HERE("Here"), TO_GO("To Go");

    private String text;

    private OrderMode(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```